# How can I boost the output current of this pulse generator (LF353, supplied with ±15 V) to above 25 mA?

Tags: operational-amplifier, current, pulse, output, schmitt-trigger

I have a pulse generator design. Everything works fine, but it is required that the output current is above 25 mA. (The 9.69 kΩ is just a variable resistance to modify the output frequency.)

[image]

[image]

Currently, with that design, I am getting 1 μA, so, as you can imagine, I have to boost it somehow, and that's where I need some help because is the only thing left for me to finish.

Comment: `Pulse Generator`, `getting 1μA` during *pulse* or *pause*? (Expecting +-1.3 mA)

Comment: It will be During!

Comment: (How many volts do you need to see 25 mA through a 10k resistor?)

Comment: Well, according to ohm's law, 250V